# $y''+a(x)y(x)=0,\quad a(x)$ is continuous function with period $T$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $y''+a(x)y(x)=0\quad$ where $a(x)$ is continuous function with period $T$. Let $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ be the basis for the solution satisfying $\phi_{1}(0)=1,\phi ' _{1}(0)=0, \phi_{2}(0)=0, \phi ' _{2}(0)=1$.
>
> Let $W(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})$ denote wronskian of $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$. Then
>
> $1)$ $W(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})=1$
>
> $2)$  $W(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})=e^x$
>
> $3)$ $\phi_{1}(T)+\phi'_{2}(T)=2$ if the given differential equation has a non trivial periodic solution with period $T$
>
> $4)$ $\phi_{1}(T)+\phi'_{2}(T)=1$ if the given differential equation has a non trivial periodic solution with period $T$

$W(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})=1$ therefore $1)$ is true and $2)$ is false.

How to proceed for $3)$ and $4)$ ?

Comment: Set $y=c_1ϕ_1+c_2ϕ_2$ and use that $y(T)=y(0)=c_1$ and also $y'(T)=y'(0)=c_2$ to find (incomplete) information about $ϕ_j(T),ϕ_j'(T)$.

Comment: yes.I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The periodic solution can be represented as $y=c_1ϕ_1+c_2ϕ_2$. It follows that
\begin{alignat}2 
y(T)&=c_1ϕ_1(T)+c_2ϕ_2(T)&&=y(0)=c_1,\\
y'(T)&=c_1ϕ_1'(T)+c_2ϕ_2'(T)&&=y'(0)=c_2.
\end{alignat} 
This looks like an eigenvector equation and leads to a determinant condition
$$
(ϕ_1(T)-1)(ϕ_2'(T)-1)-ϕ_1'(T)ϕ_2(T)=0.
$$
Then apply the insight about the Wronskian.