# Differential equations, Wronskian, periodic solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[$y''+a(x)y(x)=0,\quad a(x)$ is continuous function with period $T$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266352/848965)

Can anyone kindly explain how to approach options 3 and 4 in detail. The answer given went over my head.

I concluded that since the equation has a non trivial periodic solution then the fundamental set will also be periodic . But this seems suspicious and not right I suppose.

I don't know what the eigenvector equation or the determinant condition is , as mentioned in the answer.

Also what is the use of a(x) being periodic with period T??

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Phi(T)c=\Phi(0)c=c
$$
is the necessary and sufficient condition that $y=c_1\phi_1+c_2\phi_2$ is a periodic solution.

At the same time, in its outer terms it is the equation for the eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. If that were not an eigenvalue the only solution would be zero, then there would be no nontrivial periodic solutions.

The condition for $\lambda=1$ to be an eigenvector is that it is a root of the characteristic equation, meaning
$$
0=\det(\Phi(T)-I)=\det(\Phi(T))-{\rm trace}(\Phi(T))+1.
$$
Inserting $\det(\Phi(T))=W[\phi_1,\phi_2](T)=1$ gives the correctness of 3)

That $a$ is periodic enables you to use Floquet theory, but it does not ensure the existence of a periodic solution. However, with a non-trivial periodic solution $y$ one gets that
$$
a(t)=-\frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}
$$
can not fail to be periodic.